# PHP Unlink doesn't delete the file on Windows machine

Tags: php, windows, xampp, unlink

when I was using a Mac and MAMP the command worked fine but after moving the source code on Windows 10 and XAMPP now the following script doesn't delete the file but only move a copy of the file inside a folder (exported_files) and renaming the new file.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    error_reporting(0);

if (isset($_POST['ok']) && ($_POST['ok'] == 1))
{
    //$arrayRicevuto = implode(" ",$arrayRicevuto);
    if (!isset($_SESSION['countRows']) && empty($_SESSION['countRows']))
    {
        $_SESSION['countRows'] = $_POST['countRows'];
    }

    $data = date("dmY");

    $filename = "EstrazioneParziale_del_" . $data;

    $estensione = ".csv";

    $fileOpen = fopen($filename.$estensione, "a") or die("Impossibile aprire il file");

    foreach ($_POST['arrayFiltrato'] as $fields) {

        fputcsv($fileOpen, $fields);

    }

    fclose($fileOpen);

    $_SESSION['countRows']--;

    if ($_SESSION['countRows'] == 0)
    {
        $finalData = date("h-i-s");

        $directory="exported_files/";

        copy($filename.$estensione, $directory.$_SESSION['email']."_".$filename.$finalData.$estensione);

        unlink('$filename.$estensione');

        unset($_SESSION['countRows']);

        echo $directory.$_SESSION['email']."_".$filename.$finalData.$estensione;

    }

} else {
    echo "Errore! ";
}

?>
```

Can somebody give me a suggestion?

Many thanks in advance! :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - `error_reporting(0);` did not help. Set to catch and display.

Comment: You might want to lose the quotes as it's not nessesary when using variables. Aside from that, variables inside single quotes are processed as literal strings: `unlink($filename.$estensione);`. You might also want to try You might want to lose the quotes as it's not nessesary when using variables. Aside from that, variables inside single quotes are processed as literal strings: `unlink(realpath($filename.$estensione));` instead.

Comment: @icecub has got it for you I reckon... double quotes will process variables, single quotes will treat it literally as a string with a value of $filename.$estensione

Comment: Somehow something went wrong with my edit there, lol. But ye, if it still doesn't work, try `unlink(realpath($filename.$estensione));`

Comment: @icecub I have solved the problem using realpath. Nice suggestion!!! Thumb up for you!! I consider this question closed (how can I mark  question..closed? Sorry but I am new ^^ )

Comment: Not entirely sure how it works with Windows 10, but I suspect there might be an issue with file permissions. Could be that XAMPP user doesn't have the nessesary permissions to delete the file or maybe the file is set to read only or something.

Comment: no no I solved thanks to you :)

Comment: Alright, awesome :)

Comment: I'll turn my suggestion into an answer. You can accept that and your question is considered "anwered"

Comment: ok! Thank you man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem: Don't use single quotes around variables as it will take the variable as a literal string instead of returning you its value. For example:

```
<?php

$test = "hello";

echo '$test'; // This will print $test
echo "$test"; // This will print hello

?>
```

In [unlink();](http://php.net/unlink), you don't have to use quotes at all when using a variable.

Sometimes the system is unable to find the location of the file you're trying to delete with `unlink()`. In those cases, you can use [realpath();](http://php.net/realpath) as it will return the absolute path towards the file you're trying to delete:

```
unlink(realpath($filename.$estensione));
```